# How to make the user only enter one character at a time

Tags: python

OK so what I need to do is make my code only allow the user to enter one letter and then one symbol at a time. The example below shows what I want in a better view.

At the moment my code allows the user to enter more than one character at a time which I don't want.

```
What letter would you like to add?  hello

What symbol would you like to pair with  hello
The pairing has been added
['A#', 'M*', 'N', 'HELLOhello']
```

What I want is a message to be displayed like this and the pairing not to be added to the list.

```
What letter would you like to add?  hello

What symbol would you like to pair with  hello
You have entered more than one character, the pairing was not added
['A#', 'M*', 'N',].
```

So far my code for this section is as follows...

It would also be great for when the user enters a number in the letter section, an error message to be printed.

```
def add_pairing(clues):
    addClue = False
    letter=input("What letter would you like to add?  ").upper()
    symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with  ")
    userInput= letter + symbol
    if userInput in clues:
        print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered ")
    elif len(userInput) ==1:
        print("You can only enter one character")
    else:
        newClue = letter + symbol
        addClue = True
    if addClue == True:
        clues.append(newClue)
        print("The pairing has been added")
        print (clues)
    return clues
```

Comment: Why not have the user enter a letter and a pairing together, separated by spaces? It would easier on you and the user as well: `H1 B4 C3` etc. Also, comments should add meaning to your code, just adding comments like you have done just distracts.

Comment: How would I do that, would you be able to edit the code for me?

Comment: `a,b, c = raw_input("Enter three symbols separated by spaces").split()`

Comment: @padraic I am kind of confused where to add this in the code, would you be able to do this?

Comment: Not fully sure what you want but `str.isdigit` will check if a string only contains `digits`

Comment: I basically want the user when it asks for a letter to only enter ONE letter and no numbers and when it asks for a symbol NO letters and just one character if that makes sense...

Comment: what are legal characters?

Comment: It is working now but not fully, look at Burhlan Khalid answer and look at the comment which I left, this is the problem which I am now having...

Comment: that won't stop the user entering a digit or more than one character

Comment: Yeah your right, so now I am back to square one...

Comment: Would it be easier if I posted all of my code so you can then get a better understanding?

Comment: would be better if you told me what symbols are legal

Comment: Well thats the game, the user has to guess the letter and symbol...

Comment: So any symbols apart from letters and numbers

Comment: ok, I will add an answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure user input is with a loop:

```
while True:
    something = raw_input(prompt)

    if condition: break
```

Something set up like this will continue to ask `prompt` until `condition` is met.  You can make `condition` anything you want to test for, so for you, it would be `len(something) != 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your method can be simplified to the following if you let the user enter a letter and symbol pair:

```
def add_pairing(clues):
    pairing = input("Please enter your letter and symbol pairs, separated by a space: ")
    clues = pairing.upper().split()
    print('Your pairings are: {}'.format(clues))
    return clues
```

Comment: why use `.split(' ')`?

Comment: you don't really need to pass `clues` as an argument, as you're assigning a completely new value to it within the function.

Comment: I didn't want to change the signature as I don't know where else the method might be used.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham old habit of being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I am fan of raising and catching exceptions in similar cases. Might be shocking for people with 'C-ish' background (sloooow), but it is perfectly pythonic and quite readable and flexibile in my opinion.

Also, you should add check for characters outside of set you are expecting:

```
import string

def read_paring():
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    symbols = '*@#$%^&*' # whatever you want to allow

    letter = input("What letter would you like to add?  ").upper()
    if (len(letter) != 1) or (letter not in letters):
        raise ValueError("Only a single letter is allowed")

    msg = "What symbol would you like to pair with '{}'? ".format(letter)
    symbol = input(msg).upper()
    if (len(symbol) != 1) or (symbol not in symbols):
        raise ValueError("Only one of '{}' is allowed".format(symbols))

    return (letter, symbol)

def add_pairing(clues):
    while True:
        try:
            letter, symbol = read_paring()
            new_clue = letter + symbol
            if new_clue in clues:
                raise ValueError("This pairing already exists")
            break # everything is ok 
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err.message)
            print("Try again:")
            continue

    # do whatever you want with letter and symbol
    clues.append(new_clue)
    print(new_clue)
    return clues
```

Comment: I am getting an error, let me give you a link to my code and you might be able to figure out why... http://www.codeshare.io/mgBKs

Comment: I used raw_input() (python 2.x). You are clearly using python 3.x, so check updated version (with `input()`)

Comment: added `return clues` at the end (though it does not make much sense to return if you modified it inside). And please don't post your code to some js editor, no one is going to read it all. Post only related part, if you need to use external service, use something simple, like pastebin

Comment: It does work. There must be problem with your code elsewhere, but you've got aswer to problem you posted. If you are likely looking for someone to debug all your code, try freelancing sites...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want to  return but this will check all the entries:

```
def add_pairing(clues):
    addClue = False
    while True:
        inp = input("Enter a letter followed by a symbol, separated by a space?  ").upper().split()
        if len(inp) != 2: # make sure we only have two entries
            print ("Incorrect amount of  characters")
            continue
        if not inp[0].isalpha() or len(inp[0]) > 1:  # must be a letter and have a length of 1
            print ("Invalid letter input")
            continue
        if inp[1].isalpha() or inp[1].isdigit(): # must be anything except a digit of a letter
            print ("Invalid character input")
            continue
        userInput = inp[0] + inp[1] # all good add letter to symbol
        if userInput in clues:
            print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered ")
        else:
            newClue = userInput
            addClue = True
        if addClue:
            clues.append(newClue)
            print("The pairing has been added")
            print (clues)               
            return clues
```

Comment: Saying invalid syntax after print "Incorrect amount of  characters"

Comment: forgot you were using python 3, works now, tested it and it does exactly what it should

Comment: When I run the code and go to the option to add a pairing I get this... http://www.codeshare.io/ADoW0

Comment: I have no exceptions so you cannot get that from my code, you are not even running my code

Comment: My code does exactly what it is supposed to do, it only allows  one letter and any non alphanumeric character of length 1 so I don't see how it can cause any error, have you actually used my code as the traceback is not from my function, it is from another answer posted here

Comment: it is not possible at all, you are running someone elses code.

Comment: Just tried it again and it now works ! Dunno what happened ! I am also having one other issue in my program, would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: probably best to ask another question if it is a big issue, what is it?

Comment: Basically what I want at the end of my code is to allow the user to check there clues with the real version. So far I have one part of it working but when I choose to check them, it says that I have only got 3 clues correct and these three clues are the ones which were originally in the list of clues at the start of the program. What seems to have happened is it isn't checking the clues which I have added throughout the program. Why I asked you about this is because I am pretty sure that this is something to do when adding the clues...

Comment: The code for this option is ... http://www.codeshare.io/ZtMaC I think it is only something small...

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to keep a global list of all clues outside the functions and modify that list.

Comment: OK, would you be able to do this for me?

Comment: you should ask another question for that, this thread is getting way too long

Comment: Have to wait another 90 mins now :/

Comment: Just make a list outside of your functions and pass that list in, then all changes to the list inside the functions will be reflected in that list,

Comment: The code which you just done for adding, would you be able to do it for deleting as well?

Comment: Well because the user can enter the clue pairing, they may realise that what they have entered is wrong so they get the option to delete it...

Comment: Getting this error now... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\test\test.py", line 245, in <module>
    add_pairing(clues)
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\test\test.py", line 81, in add_pairing
    if userInput in clues:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable